# javascript freezing tabs, and input

Tags: javascript

I am making a JavaScript onkeypress function.

```
    function report() {
        while (1 == 1) {
        window.onkeypress = function(event) {
            /* from this point down, keylog functions.    */
            // above is a variable
            if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                console.log("Spacebar._rep")
            }
            if (event.keycode == 33) {
                console.log("escalation-Mark._rep")
            }
            if (event.keycode == 34) {
                console.log("quotation-Mark._rep")
            }
            if (event.keycode == 35) {
                console.log("hashtag._rep")
            }
            if (event.keycode == 36) {
                console.log("dollar-Sign._rep")
            }
            if (event.keycode == 37) {
                console.log("percent-Symbol._rep")
            }
            if (event.keycode == 38) {
                console.log("pi")
            }
        }
    }
}
report()
```

whenever i run this code, however it freezes all forms of input, i can still scroll, open tabs, and click. I cannot close the tab, reload, or change the JavaScript code. I have tried it with and without variables, and i have tried modifying it. It works absolutely fine when their is only one key function, but once i add several it freezes.
I have de-dented, and indented nothing has worked.
I have checked out a few other similar questions, which said to do things like remove variable, and i did that and it still freezes.

Comment: In javascript you don't have to use the `while(1==1)`. The event listener will respond for all events attached to `window` variable. Using the while loop creates infinite listeners which is freezing the app.

Comment: *"I have de-dented, and indented nothing has worked."* Indentation (white space) is mostly irrelevant in JavaScript. You could write everything in a single line and it would still work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an infinite loop which freezes that tab.

```
while (1 == 1) {
    //infinite loop
}
```

Instead of doing that, just attach a listener to the window that fires a callback each time the event occurs:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    console.log(e)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> The onkeypress property sets and returns the onKeyPress event handler
>   code for the current element.

As you current element is `window` when you run `report` the event listener will listen to any keypress, there is no really need of a `while` statement, it actually make freeze you app.

```js
function report() {
  window.onkeypress = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      console.log("Spacebar._rep")
    }
    if (event.keycode == 33) {
      console.log("escalation-Mark._rep")
    }
    if (event.keycode == 34) {
      console.log("quotation-Mark._rep")
    }
    if (event.keycode == 35) {
      console.log("hashtag._rep")
    }
    if (event.keycode == 36) {
      console.log("dollar-Sign._rep")
    }
    if (event.keycode == 37) {
      console.log("percent-Symbol._rep")
    }
    if (event.keycode == 38) {
      console.log("pi")
    }
  }
}
report()
```

```html
1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is freezing because `while (1==1)` is running infinitely, you should not write you code like this. It is blocking the browser

```
    window.onkeypress = function(event) {
        /* from this point down, keylog functions.    */
        // above is a variable
        if (event.keyCode == 32) {
            console.log("Spacebar._rep")
        }
        if (event.keycode == 33) {
            console.log("escalation-Mark._rep")
        }
        if (event.keycode == 34) {
            console.log("quotation-Mark._rep")
        }
        if (event.keycode == 35) {
            console.log("hashtag._rep")
        }
        if (event.keycode == 36) {
            console.log("dollar-Sign._rep")
        }
        if (event.keycode == 37) {
            console.log("percent-Symbol._rep")
        }
        if (event.keycode == 38) {
            console.log("pi")
        }
    }
```

this is all that is needed, the code will be "asynchronously" called

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "while (1 == 1)". It seems like it doesn't leave that while-loop.